# Buildfire: Redirect issue after login in Disqus account

Tags: angularjs, buildfire

I'm working on a plugin for Buildfire that requires the integration of Disqus comments, the plugin is based on Angularjs 1.x and displays the data from a website feed.

I have successfully integrated the Disqus comments on the plugin and Disqus correctly display the comment for each post from feed, but when user tries to login to Disqus its not redirecting back to my app page after login.

Here are my findings:
- For login disqus opens the login page in new window that's handled by Buildfire and login page is displayed in inapp browser.
- After the successful login disqus tried to close the window, but it fails since page is in inapp browser, and user interface hangs on the blank page.

I'm just wondering if this is possible to detect the URL change in buildfire, so we can hook code to detect the post login URL and display the plugin page in app.

PS: Login correctly works when testing on buildfire Software Development Kit(https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk), this issue is only on actual device.

```
$window.disqus_config = function () { 
    this.page.url = WidgetMedia.item.link; 
};
if (!$window.DISQUS) { 
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script'); 
    s.src = 'https://<site>.disqus.com/embed.js'; 
    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date()); 
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s); 
} 
else { 
    $window.DISQUS.reset({ reload: true, config: function () { 
        this.page.url = WidgetMedia.item.link; 
    } }); 
}
```

Comment: How are you handling opening the new window to Disqus? Showing your code may be helpful.

Comment: @attila226 I'm not handling the opening of new window, its handled by BuildFire.

Comment: @attila226 so basically I'm using "disqus universal code" to show the comments on page, so interface of disqus comments including the login links are generated by disqus, and when user clicks on any link in app its opened in inapp browser by BuildFire, there is no code involved in this process.

Comment: So you are using buildfire.navigation.openWindow but the callback is not triggering because it is using the in app browser?

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear before, but I'm not calling the "buildfire.navigation.openWindow" or any other function to open the login window, popup is build and triggered by disqus code(disqus embed script provided by disqus universal code) and disqus is internally using window.open

Comment: If you can provide a code snippet of what you're doing, I think it would be helpful. There may be alternative ways to accomplish what you're trying to achieve. In terms of if BuildFire can detect a URL change in an app browser, I don't believe there's anything in the API that triggers based on that type of event.

Comment: @attila226 here is the code I'm using in controller to render the disqus comments 

$window.disqus_config = function () { this.page.url = WidgetMedia.item.link; }; if (!$window.DISQUS) { var d = document, s = d.createElement('script'); s.src = 'https://<site>.disqus.com/embed.js'; s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date()); (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s); } else { $window.DISQUS.reset({ reload: true, config: function () { this.page.url = WidgetMedia.item.link; } }); }

Comment: I dont believe you will be able to open a window directly from the plugin. Remember, its not a web page strictly speaking. You many need to hijack the window.open function to force it to pass through the framework. That being said, if it redirects or even sets a cookie you may not have access to that.